# Why isn't my html linking to my print CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, printing, stylesheet

cssI am trying to create a print style sheet with css to connect to my html webpage. I added the style sheet line under  and my style sheet is a css file named print.css in the same directory as my html file. This is my first time doing this, is there anything that I am doing incorrectly as far as procedure?

Thanks for any advice

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"/>

<style>
   .
   .
   .
</style>

</head>
```

CSS

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 body{
 width: 8000px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .section{
  width: 2000px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size:20px;
  page-break-after: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;



  p a:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  font-size: 50%;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: the URI is pointed to `href="print.html"`, try changing it to `href="print.css"`. You're also defining the media type as print, which only applies to printing, use `media="screen"`

Comment: I fixed it... and tried it again in my code. I tried .html and .css just in case, but neither accept my changes in the style sheets. Thanks though

Comment: Have you got a lin to your site? It could be the file path or something like that

Comment: What changes are you trying?  Are you going into Print Preview to check the changes?  You know background color's are ignored when printing...?

Comment: yeah, I should have put that in the description. I am trying to create a printing page. I have text inside of separate divs so the text takes up about 800px in each div. I need it to spread the width of the page. I would also like to add a header.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're missing a final `}` at the end of the `.section` styles.

Comment: 8000px wide for the body?? That's pretty wide. What issues are you having that make you think that the CSS document is not being recognized by the HTML document?

Answer (score 3):

CSS files cannot contain HTML.  This is all your print.css file should contain:

```
body{
    width: 8000px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.section{
    width: 2000px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size:20px;
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

p a:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    font-size: 50%;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried that and it still doesn't work. Maybe it's the editor or the version of HTML (I am using html5).

Answer (score 0):

You have included HTML within your CSS file which will not work. You need to remove the `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> and <style>` tags.

You have also forgotten to close your `.section` css with a closing bracket so it will look like this:

```
.section{
width: 2000px;
float: left;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
font-size:20px;
page-break-after: always;
page-break-inside: avoid; }
```

Other than that check your CSS file has the same name as specified in the `link` tag - it may be possible that you have a spelling mistake somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

The href is wrong in your call to the css file:

You are calling to an HTML file that probably doesn't exist

```
<link href="print.html" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
```

If it does exist extract your css from that HTML file and put it into a CSS Document, then link to the file like this:

```
<link href="print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
```

Inside that file wrap your styles in this tag:

@media print {
   your css here
}

That should do exactly what you need it to do.